# Java 8 Steam Group By on two properties and get average of third property

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have below class objects in one ArrayList:

```
new Pojo("Football","M",1000)
new Pojo("Football","M",1000)
new Pojo("Cricket","F",500)
new Pojo("Cricket","F",1500)
new Pojo("Cricket","M",500)
new Pojo("Cricket","M",500)
```

I want to get the average points of the "Sports" with respect to "Gender".
I came across Java 8 Streams and seems like it is good to use it here but I don't know to implement it.

I have tried it like below:

```
Map<Object,Long> mp = pojoList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.sport,Collectors.counting()));
```

It's working good, giving me a sports count but I want to apply one more filter of gender and get the average point.

The output which I want:

```
new PojoOutput("Football","M",1000)
new PojoOutput("Cricket","F",1000)
new PojoOutput("Cricket","M",500)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group to a map by using 2 `groupingBy` calls, one of them being the downstream to the other:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> res = pojos.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pojo::getSport,
            Collectors.groupingBy(Pojo::getGender, 
                                  Collectors.averagingDouble(i -> i.getPoints()))));
```

This results in `{Cricket={F=1000.0, M=500.0}, Football={M=1000.0}}`, which you can easily convert to `Pojo` instances using something like this:

```
List<Pojo> groups = result.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(sport -> sport.getValue()
                        .entrySet().stream()
                        .map(gender -> new Pojo(sport.getKey(), 
                                                gender.getKey(), 
                                                gender.getValue())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Result with a generated `toString`:

```
[Pojo [sport=Cricket, gender=F, points=1000.0], 
 Pojo [sport=Cricket, gender=M, points=500.0], 
 Pojo [sport=Football, gender=M, points=1000.0]]
```

Comment: @ernest_k- Thanks for your response. It's working like a charm. Saved my time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `SimpleEntry` to group your data with. After that you can map the results back to your `PojoOutput`:

```
List<PojoOutput> mp = pojoList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(x.getSport(), x.getGender()), Collectors.averagingInt(Pojo::getScore)))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new PojoOutput(e.getKey().getKey(), e.getKey().getValue(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can improve that solution a bit using your `PojoOutput` directly in the group by clause. Therefore the `PojoOutput` needs a constructor with `Pojo` as attribute and implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` according to the fields: For example something similar to that:

```
private static class PojoOutput {
    private String sport;
    private String gender;
    private double average;

    public PojoOutput(Pojo pojo) {
        this.sport = pojo.getSport();
        this.gender = pojo.getGender();
    }

    public void setAverage(double average) {
        this.average = average;
    }

    // equals, hashCode and getter
}
```

Now you can use that class like that:

```
List<PojoOutput> mp = pojoList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PojoOutput::new, Collectors.averagingInt(Pojo::getScore)))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .peek(p -> p.getKey().setAverage(p.getValue()))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The result in both cases is:

```
PojoOutput[sport='Cricket', gender='M', average=500.0]
PojoOutput[sport='Football', gender='M', average=1000.0]
PojoOutput[sport='Cricket', gender='F', average=1000.0]
```

Comment: Instead of `x -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(x.getSport(), x.getGender())`, you can also use `x -> Arrays.asList(x.getSport(), x.getGender())`, which can easily extended to more than two values when needed.

Comment: @Holger Yes, but you can use different types (e.g. String and Integer) with `SimpleEntry`.

Comment: Well, yes, that makes the subsequent construction of `PojoOutput` easier. A list would work too, but might require type casts.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Arrays::asList` for the Key that you want to group by:

```
 pojoList.stream() 
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                     x -> Arrays.asList(x.getSport(), x.getGender()),
                     Collectors.averagingInt(Pojo::getScore)));
```

Or if you have a `PojoOutput`, simply replace the `x -> Arrays.asList(x.getSport(), x.getGender())` with that constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You want the key of the map to be [sport, gender]. So you need to create a class `SportAndGenderKey` containing these two properties and a proper equals and hashCode methods, and then you need to group your objects by `SportAndGenderKey`.

And then you want to use an averaging collector rather than a counting collector.

Note: the key could simply be a List containing the two properties, but I find it less clear than a dedicated key class.

Answer (score 0):

As @JB Nizet said you can follow bellow code:

```
list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> 
                new PojoOutput(p.getSport(), p.getGender()),Pojo::getPoint, (v1, v2) -> (v1 + v2) / 2))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(entry -> entry.getKey().setAverage(entry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

just override `equals` and `hashCode` methods in `PojoOutput` class based on two properties (*sport* & *geneder*)

and also:

```
public PojoOutput setAverage(Integer average) {
    this.average = average;
    return this;
}
```